# Get code of an exec file

Tags: python, macos, exec, extract

I have a exec file. To run it I need to change a value in the code. I haven't written the code by myself so I don't have access to the code.

Is there any way to extract the code of the file?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Be more specific or give an example

Comment: What do you mean by "exec file" ? I guess you have a binary executable file compiled from Python code that you want to reverse & modify, is that it ?

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to coding and those executable files, yes Etene.

Comment: This might be difficult if you're new to the subject -- what you want to do is called reverse engineering and is far from being a beginner topic :) [This question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-do-you-reverse-engineer-an-exe-compiled-with-pyinstaller) is pretty much the same as yours but formulated differently, it should give you something to start with. Unfortunately a step-by-step approach is not going to be feasible here because of the complexity... you'll have to get at least a bit familiar with the subject.

Comment: Alright thank you very much :-) I'll try it! Practice creates masters!